# Executable process XML to excel with Matlab

Tags: xml, excel, matlab, import, executable

I would like make an executable program what can process big XML file (80Mb) into excel. I tried with Matlab, I tried xmlread, but it failed because not enough memory to process such a big XML. I could do it if I read the XML line by line but it takes a lot of time (1hour) The XML has more than one node, one application can contain more station, one station can contain more transmitter and one trasmitter can have more freqvency. I have one-to-many relationships, my XML structure:

```
<SPECTRAEXCHANGE>
<APPLICATION>
<SV_SV_ID>kClong</SV_SV_ID>
<SS_SS_ID>kClong</SS_SS_ID>
<AP_NAME>kCstring (64)</AP_NAME>
<AP_PRJ_IDENT>kCstring (32)</AP_PRJ_IDENT>
<STATION>
<TCS_NAME>kCstring (64)</TCS_NAME>
<TCS_CALL>kCstring (256)</TCS_CALL>
<HORIZONTAL_ELEVATIONS>
<HORIZONTAL_ELEVATION>
<HE_AZIMUT>kCdouble</HE_AZIMUT>
<HE_ELEVATION>kCdouble</HE_ELEVATION>
</HORIZONTAL_ELEVATION>
</HORIZONTAL_ELEVATIONS>
<TRANSMITTER>
<EQP_EQUIP_NAME>kCstring (128)</EQP_EQUIP_NAME>
<EQP_EQUIP_TYPE>kCstring (16)</EQP_EQUIP_TYPE>
<FREQUENCY>
<EFL_FREQ>kCdouble</EFL_FREQ>
<LINK>kCdouble</LINK>
<COORDINATED_FREQUENCY>
<COF_DAT>kWrDate</COF_DAT>
</COORDINATED_FREQUENCY>
</FREQUENCY>
</TRANSMITTER>
<RECEIVER>
<EQP_EQUIP_NAME>kCstring (128)</EQP_EQUIP_NAME>
<EQP_EQUIP_TYPE>kCstring (16)</EQP_EQUIP_TYPE>
<FREQUENCY>
<EFL_FREQ>kCdouble</EFL_FREQ>
<LINK>kCdouble</LINK>
<COORDINATED_FREQUENCY>
<COF_DAT>kWrDate</COF_DAT>
</COORDINATED_FREQUENCY>
</FREQUENCY>
</RECEIVER>
</STATION>
</APPLICATION>
</SPECTRAEXCHANGE>
```

The connection between TRANSMITTER and RECEIVER is the LINK.
Can you help me to import it in anyway?

Comment: why don't you use java ? It does not read all of the XML into memory.

Comment: i am not familiar with java, if you can give me the first steps maybe i can finish it

Comment: If your input files are very large then using a SAX reader would take less memory: here's an example in VBA (since you want the data in excel)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626653/how-can-i-improve-the-speed-of-xml-parsing-in-vba